# Writing Kvo context in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, key-value-observing

In **ObjC**

```
static void * const kKVOContext = (void*)&kKVOContext;
[self.superview removeObserver:self.parent forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentOffset)) context:kKVOContext];
```

`contentOffset` is `UIScrollView` property.

I have written this into swift as-

**Swift**

```
 var kKVOContext = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: 4 * 4, alignedTo: 1)
 self.superview?.removeObserver(self.parent!, forKeyPath: NSStringFromSelector(#selector(getter: UIScrollView.contentOffset)), context: &kKVOContext)
```

So in Swift
Is this correct way or it should be diffrent  `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`? or How can i write `kKVOContext` in swift ?

Comment: what about using `didSet` ?

Comment: I don't know how to accomplish, can you add as  answer ?

Comment: What is your purpose to add KVO in scrollview even though you have scrollview delegate methods , If you don't aware about delegate methods  just google it how to set delegate of uiscrollview

Answer (score 1):

You could use swift 4's new feature

```
// Setting up KVO
 observation = scrollView.observe(\.contentOffset, changeHandler: { (object, change) in
       print("Updated Value: \(object.contentOffset)")
 })

 // Deiniting or invalidating the observation token ends the observation
 observation.invalidate()

 // After invalidating KVO doesn't trigger anymore
```

Answer (score 1):

This Objective C code is bad; context is used with being initalized.  In Swift it will be initialized to 0.  Anyways, the context is for you to use.  Its an arbitrary value that lets you specify why you are observing this value or who is obversing this value, apart from the object and keypath.  Its basically a user cookie.  Thats why this code doesn't crash; the OS doesn't use the context, you do.  In Swift you can just pass in the reference to any reference type, or you can actually omit the parameter; it defaults to nil if you aren't using it: `self.superview?.removeObserver(self.parent!, forKeyPath: "contentOffset")`

Comment: Why is the Objective-C code bad? `kKVOContext` contains the address of itself.